# Post to wall without feed dialog giving "NetworkOnMainThreadexception" | Android

Tags: android

I am trying to post on users wall from my application without showing the feed dialog box. I have an activity with an `EditText getmessage` and a `Button with onClick()=postToWall`. I am following this question:
[Android Facebook Post On Wall Without Dialog Warnings](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9945153/android-facebook-post-on-wall-without-dialog-warnings)

Here is my code:

```
public void postToWall(View v){
        String message = getmessage.getText().toString();
        postMessage(message);       
    }

    public void postMessage(String message){
        Log.d("test", "testing post to wall");
        try{
            String response;
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", message);           
            response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");

            Log.d("test", "got response "+response);

            if(response == null || response.equals("")){
                Log.v("Error", "Blank");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Below is the log:

```
  06-06 20:03:19.726: I/ActivityManager(78): Displayed com.MyApp/.fbShare: +146ms
06-06 20:03:24.816: D/test(736): testing post to wall
06-06 20:03:24.828: W/System.err(736): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-06 20:03:24.836: W/System.err(736):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
06-06 20:03:24.836: W/System.err(736):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
06-06 20:03:24.846: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
06-06 20:03:24.856: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
06-06 20:03:24.856: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
06-06 20:03:24.856: W/System.err(736):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:164)
06-06 20:03:24.856: W/System.err(736):  at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:193)
06-06 20:03:24.866: W/System.err(736):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:751)
06-06 20:03:24.866: W/System.err(736):  at com.MyApp.fbShare.postMessage(fbShare.java:56)
06-06 20:03:24.866: W/System.err(736):  at com.MyApp.fbShare.postToWall(fbShare.java:47)
06-06 20:03:24.866: W/System.err(736):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 20:03:24.866: W/System.err(736):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 20:03:24.876: W/System.err(736):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
06-06 20:03:24.876: W/System.err(736):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-06 20:03:24.876: W/System.err(736):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-06 20:03:24.876: W/System.err(736):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-06 20:03:24.886: W/System.err(736):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-06 20:03:24.886: W/System.err(736):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 20:03:24.886: W/System.err(736):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-06 20:03:24.886: W/System.err(736):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 20:03:24.896: W/System.err(736):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 20:03:24.896: W/System.err(736):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-06 20:03:24.896: W/System.err(736):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-06 20:03:24.896: W/System.err(736):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Am I missing something here? I am grateful for any help.
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange NetworkOnMainThreadException in Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995364/strange-networkonmainthreadexception-in-android-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with 3.0 (I think) the system throws an exception if you attempt to use the network on the Main (UI) thread. They chose to make the system do this to encourage developers not to put long running tasks (such as network operations) on the Main thread.

In order to fix your problem you need to move your network operations(e.g. calls to postMessage()) to a background thread. There are a few approaches. Check out [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or look into using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) / [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html). Many examples can be found online if you search for something like "Android create background threads"

Also [this tutorial made by Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) is awesome for learning about this stuff.

Comment: The tutorial by vogel helped. By doing the posting work in a background thread, it now allows me to post. I was unaware of the issue. Got to learn! thanks.